# How can I run only a specific test in a Perl distribution?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

This question is related to [this question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188515/creating-unit-tests-for-a-perl-framework-with-multiple-modules). I have multiple test files (A.t, B.t, C.t etc) created to test their respective module A, B, C & so on. But when I do a make test, it runs all the tests. But, when I'm working on a specific module say B, I'd like to run unit tests for that module. After I'm done with my changes, I'll run the whole suite.

So is there any way to do like `make test B`, which will run only the tests using B.t? And when I say some thing like "make test all" it runs all the tests under the "t" dir? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just run the test that I want to run:

```
 % make; perl -Mblib t/B.t
```

You can do the same thing with `prove`, too.

---

That `-Mblib` loads the module [blib](http://www.metacpan.org/module/blib) which merely adds *blib/lib* (and various special directories under it) to `@INC` for you. It comes with Perl. `prove` should do the same thing with the `-b` switch.

My command is really two parts: the `make` (or `./Build` for [Module::Build](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Module::Build)). This builds the source and moves Perl modules and other files into the "build library", or *blib*, as an intermediate step in the full installation. Normally `make test` works against the versions in *blib* and refreshes that for me. Since I'm testing on my own, I ensure that I refresh *blib* myself and include it in Perl's module search path.

Despite the fact that I know all this, you might be surprised that I often forget to do one of those steps and end up testing against the wrong version of things, whether the fully installed old version (forgot `-Mblib`) or the old development sources (forgot `make`). This leads me to debugging statements such as:

```
print "No really, this is the Foo version. kthnxbye\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Executing tests directly through `perl` works.  The `prove` command was designed to simplify the process, save keystrokes, and shorten the test-debug-test cycle.

`prove` was designed to work on multiple tests at a time, which you can't do invoking via `perl`.  For instance, you can do:

```
prove t/*.t
prove t/     # Same as t/*.t
prove t/dev/ # Run only tests in t/dev/
prove -r t/  # Runs all .t files in t/ and any directories below.
```

The modern `prove` also has many features for handling suites of tests and modifying how the TAP output from the tests is displayed.

`prove --help` will show you all `prove`'s options, and `prove --man` will show you the manual page.

Comment: Here is the [`prove` docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/prove)