# XML::LibXSLT failed to install on macOS Catalina

Tags: perl, xslt

I was using `cpan` to try to install `XML::LibXSLT`. `sudo cpan`-> `install XML::LibXSLT` but couldn't install it.

Here's the detailed error message:

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better 

logging
Reading '/Users/chris/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 06 Jul 2019 16:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::LibXSLT'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.01)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.074)
Checksum for /Users/chris/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz ok
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.29)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20181129_28)
Configuring S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
running xslt-config... ok
looking for -lxslt... yes
looking for -lexslt... yes
running pkg-config libexslt... ok
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for XML::LibXSLT
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz
cp LibXSLT.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXSLT.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for LibXSLT ()
chmod 644 "LibXSLT.bs"
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LibXSLT.bs blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bs 644
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/Users/chris/.cpan/build/XML-LibXSLT-1.96-5/typemap'  LibXSLT.xs > LibXSLT.xsc
mv LibXSLT.xsc LibXSLT.c
cc -c  -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/include/libxml2 -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.96\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.96\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_EXSLT LibXSLT.c
cc -c  -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/include/libxml2 -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.96\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.96\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_BLANK -DHAVE_EXSLT perl-libxml-mm.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/lib" cc  -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong  LibXSLT.o perl-libxml-mm.o  -o blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle  \
           -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -licucore -lm -L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/lib -lexslt -lpthread -licucore -lxml2   \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle
Manifying 1 pod document
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
CPAN: CPAN::DistnameInfo loaded ok (v0.12)
Running make test for SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LibXSLT.bs blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01basic.t ............... 1/4 

Compiled against:    libxslt 10129, libxml2 20909
Running:             libxslt 10129, libxml2 20909
Compiled with EXSLT: yes

t/01basic.t ............... ok   
t/02dromeds.t ............. ok   
t/03input.t ............... 1/28 I/O warning : failed to load external entity "foo.xml"
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "foo.xml"

#   Failed test 'Threw: '
#   at t/03input.t line 88.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "foo.xml"
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "foo.xml"

#   Failed test 'Transform Threw: '
#   at t/03input.t line 130.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "foo.xml"
compilation error: file unknown-7fbc7df2a970 element import
xsl:import : unable to load foo.xml
 at t/03input.t line 171.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 11.
t/03input.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 19/28 subtests 
t/04params.t .............. ok   
t/05quick.t ............... ok     
t/06entities.t ............ ok   
t/06output.t .............. ok     
t/07blankdoc.t ............ 1/5 I/O warning : failed to load external entity "foo"
t/07blankdoc.t ............ ok   
t/08literal.t ............. ok   
t/09exslt.t ............... ok   
t/10functions.t ........... ok     
t/11utf8.t ................ ok     
t/12import.t .............. ok   
t/13error.t ............... 1/28 xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
t/13error.t ............... ok     
t/14security.t ............ 1/26 I/O warning : failed to load external entity "allow.xml"

#   Failed test 'Output matches foo'
#   at t/14security.t line 100.
#                   '<?xml version="1.0"?>
# <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Know Your Dromedaries</title></head><body><h1>allow.xml</h1><p>foo: </p></body></html>
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^:foo: Text here)'
error : Operation in progress
error : Operation in progress
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/allow.xml"

#   Failed test 'Output matches.'
#   at t/14security.t line 198.
#                   '<?xml version="1.0"?>
# <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Know Your Dromedaries</title></head><body><h1>http://localhost/allow.xml</h1><p>foo: </p></body></html>
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^:foo: Text here)'
error : Operation in progress
error : Operation in progress
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 26.
t/14security.t ............ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/26 subtests 
t/15misc.t ................ ok   
t/cpan-changes.t .......... skipped: Test::CPAN::Changes required for this test
t/pod.t ................... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
t/rt71345_a.t ............. ok   
t/rt71345_b.t ............. ok   
t/style-trailing-space.t .. skipped: Test::TrailingSpace required for trailing space test.
t/xml-grammar-failures.t .. ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/03input.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 11 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  8, 11
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 28 tests but ran 11.
t/14security.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 26 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  9, 22
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=22, Tests=229,  5 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr  0.07 sys +  2.89 cusr  0.77 csys =  3.85 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/22 test programs. 4/229 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz
```

I've tried this on the Terminal and in the IDE. But it still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To debug this further, try to run the given test manually (download the distribution: `wget https://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/XML/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.96.tar.gz`, extract and run `perl Makefile.PL; make; make test`, then run the given test explicitly for example `perl t/03input.t`. What output do you get?

Comment: `Can't locate XML/LibXSLT.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::LibXSLT module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level */5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1) at t/03input.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/03input.t line 6.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.`

Comment: I seem to get it working using the `cpanm XML::LibXSLT --force` to install it.

Comment: Yes that will probably work fine. I was just curious why the test failed. I forgot that you needed to use build library when running the test. See [How can I run only a specific test in a Perl distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2203994/2173773). So you need to run the test as `perl -Mblib t/03input.t`.

Comment: You may also add an issue at [the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/shlomif/perl-XML-LibXSLT/issues) or update [this issue](https://github.com/shlomif/perl-XML-LibXSLT/issues/1) which seems to be similar to yours